# comparing strings in python

Tags: python, string-comparison

```
def find_last(search, target):
    for index, character in reversed(list(enumerate(search))):
        if character in target:
            return index
        else:
            return -1
```

> suppose search="aaaaa" and target="aa", output should=3, not 4.
>     I am trying to get the last position where the two strings compare

Answer (score 3):

Currently what you're doing is comparing each character from the `search` string in reverse order and seeing if it's in `target`. If it is, you prematurely return the wrong index.

Instead, I would recommend using the [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rfind#str.rfind) method:

```
>>> 'aaaaa'.rfind('aa')
3
```

`str.rfind` is basically the same thing as the `str.index` method except it searches for the first needle from the right of the haystack.

**Edit:** In order to treat empty needles as being present at the rightmost index, you can use the following return expression:

```
def find_last(search, target):
        return target and search.rfind(target) or len(search)
```

Comment: but if i have a string "22222222", and target="", out put should be 9, not -1. but rfind does not put this scenario into consideration

Comment: @SpencerJosephs Ah, I see. I've edited the answer to make it return the length of the search string if the target is an empty string.